# Initializing C struct with unions declared in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, unions

This question is specifically about options in **C++17**. Assuming following declaration in C library (I cannot change them):

```c
typedef enum {
    TYPEA = 0,
    TYPEB = 2,
    TYPEC = 4
} SPECIFIC_TYPE_t;

typedef struct {
    uint16_t Method : 1;
    uint16_t Access : 2;
    uint16_t VendorSpecific : 1;
    uint16_t Direction : 1;
    uint16_t Persistent : 1;
    uint16_t Internal : 4;
    uint16_t Reserved : 6;           
} PROPERTY_t;

typedef RESULT_t (*CB_DataPointRead_t) (void *Service, uint8_t Pinpoint, bool VendorSpecific,
                                        uint16_t GroupID, uint16_t ElementID, void *Data,
                                        uint8_t *DataLengthInOut);
typedef RESULT_t (*CB_DataPointWrite_t) (void *service, uint8_t Pinpoint, bool VendorSpecific,
                                         uint16_t GroupID, uint16_t ElementID, void *Data,
                                         uint8_t DataLength);

typedef struct {
    uint16_t GroupID;
    uint16_t ElementID;
    uint8_t Pinpoint;
    SPECIFIC_TYPE_t Type;
    uint8_t Size;
    PROPERTY_t Property;
    union {
        struct {
            CB_DataPointRead_t Read;
            CB_DataPointWrite_t Write;
        } Callback;
        struct {
            void *Data;
        } DirectAccess;
    } AccessType;
} DataPoint_t;
```

### Status in pure C

To initialize the last element designator initializers work well in C:

```c
uint16t dataPointValue = 0;
const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig = {
    /*...*/,
    .DirectAccess = { (void*)&dataPointValue; }
};
```

### Designator initializers in C++

They appear in C++20 and aren't compatible with C in many aspects.

### Problem

I'd like to initialize variable like `firstDatapointConfig` as const qualified in C++17. So far I don't see a way other than write a function in C (compiled as C code) and return the initialized structure to a variable before use. I tried various ways, including gnuc++17 which handles designator initializers, except it tells me:

```
error: 'const DataPoint_t' has no non-static data member named 'DirectAccess'
```

and MSVC don't digest this method of initialization at all without C++20 enabled.

Addressing the last element outside initializer, don't work either:

```
datapoint.DirectAccess = { &value };
```

results in the following error:

```
error: 'struct DataPoint_t' has no member named 'DirectAccess'
```

### Comment

It was much easier to use these structures in Rust after processing them through bindgen :-)

### Question

Is there a way to initialize the variable of `DataPoint_t` type in C++17 with `DirectAccess` element filled with the right value?

Comment: "*They appear in C++20 and aren't compatible with C in many aspects.*" They are 100% compatible with C99 designated initializers. But C99 designated initializers are *not* 100% compatible with C++20's version. That is, if you write valid C++20 code that uses designated initializers, it will be valid C99 code too (all other things being valid). But not the other way around.

Comment: OK, point taken.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to initialize the variable of DataPoint_t type in C++17 with DirectAccess element filled with the right value?

Yes, even though my way of doing it is a little cumbersome. There may be easier ways:

```
// Make a usable type of that anonymous entity:
using AccessType_t = decltype(DataPoint_t::AccessType);

// Use the new type and prepare what you need:
AccessType_t at;
at.DirectAccess.Data = nullptr;

// initialize your DataPoint_t
const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig{1,2,3,TYPEA,4, PROPERTY_t{}, at};
```

If you do this a lot you could make a helper function:

```cpp
using AccessType_t = decltype(DataPoint_t::AccessType);
using Callback_t = decltype(AccessType_t::Callback);    
using DirectAccess_t = decltype(AccessType_t::DirectAccess);

template<class U>
constexpr auto init_AccessType(U u) {
    AccessType_t at;

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<U,Callback_t>) {
        at.Callback = u;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<U,DirectAccess_t>) {
        at.DirectAccess = u;
    } else {
        // uninitialized
    }
    return at;
}

const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig{1,2,3,TYPEA,4, PROPERTY_t{},
                                       init_AccessType(DirectAccess_t{nullptr})};
```

Comment: `decltype` has a specific rule which makes `decltype(DataPoint_t::AccessType)` work as needed here.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks! Edited!

Comment: Thanks, @TedLyngmo. While doesn't really solve my problem for clear initialization, by reminding me `decltype()` I learnt something new today.

Comment: @MichałFita That's something at least :-) You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to initialize variable like firstDatapointConfig as const qualified in C++17

With all that C++ has to offer:

```
constexpr DataPoint_t create_DataPoint_t(uint16_t *v) {
    DataPoint_t r{};
    r.AccessType.DirectAccess.Data = v;
    return r;
}    
const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig = create_DataPoint_t(&dataPointValue);
```

with designated initializers:

```
const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig2 = {
    .AccessType = {
        .DirectAccess = {
            .Data = &dataPointValue
        }
    }
};
```

> Addressing the last element outside initializer, don't work either:
>
> ```
> datapoint.DirectAccess = { &value };
> ```

Because there is no such element, there is `datapoint.AccessType.DirectAccess.Data`.

> To initialize the last element designator initializers work well in C:
>
> ```
> uint16t dataPointValue = 0;
> const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig = {
>     /*...*/,
>     .DirectAccess = { (void*)&dataPointValue; }
> };
> ```

The presented code is invalid - `uint16t` is meant to be `uint16_t` and `;` is a typo. And still after fixing the typos, no, the presented code is invalid in "pure C" and "does not work well" [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/qz4E5Y). There is no such thing as `DirectAccess` in `DataPoint_t` - there is such member in the unnamed union declared inside `DataPoint_t`. You can do **in C**:

```
const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig3_in_C = {
    .AccessType = {
        .DirectAccess = { (void*)&dataPointValue }
    }
};
```

or

```
const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig4_in_C = {
    .AccessType.DirectAccess = { (void*)&dataPointValue }
};
```

or

```
const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig4_in_C = {
    .AccessType.DirectAccess.Data = (void*)&dataPointValue
};
```

The cast to `void*` is superfluous - all pointers are implicitly converted to `void*`. Note that the following:

```
const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig5_in_C = {
    .AccessType = { (void*)&dataPointValue }
};
```

would be equal to:

```
const DataPoint_t firstDatapointConfig6_in_C = {
    .AccessType.Callback.Read = (void*)&dataPointValue
};
```

Most probably you are coding under `-fms-extensions` with GNU gcc or with MSVC, in which case you should be aware that you are using [an extension that imports unnamed structure members to parent structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/z2cx9y4f(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). The code is invalid in "pure C", it's using an extension to C.

Comment: I don't see where they are using the extension you link to in the last paragraph?

Comment: Cool. C answers aren't much helpful. I use MSVC 2019 & GCC 9.1, but unless the extension isn't enabled by default, I don't turn it on. Designated initializers work in GCC in gnuc++17 mode, but don't work with MSVC in C++17 mode. The first snippet seem to work best for my needs. Thanks.